# How to make scanned image a 16-bit file with appropriate size for ImageJ

Tags: imagej

So my objective is to quantify dot blots in ImageJ using integrated pixel density after removing background. My issue is this: I need the image in a format that will be small enough to open in ImageJ with no loss of quality and is also 16-bit. I need to do a non-uniform background correction, and want to use this plug in to do so, and 16-bit is required: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~cquammen/imagej/nonuniform_background_removal.html

I scanned the image in tiff format, however the image was over 170 MB and would not open in ImageJ due to memory (even when running ImageJ from command line to free up more memory). I know jpeg is not wise due to quality loss. Does anyone have any ideas on what format I should save the image in after scanning to get it in 16 bit format and proper size to work with in ImageJ? The image is a piece of white paper with 6 sections, each section containing a small membrane with spots on it. Each membrane is a different concentration, so I must average the four spots and correct for background as well. The issue is the non-uniform background noise I must correct for.

Thank you very much, I am very frustrated with this and need to get my quantification completed! This is my first time using ImageJ and quantifying biological data and I know very little about image processing and analysis.

Thanks again

Comment: Did you actually get an `OutOfMemory` error? You can [give ImageJ more memory](http://imagej.net/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_avoid_running_out_of_memory_.28OutOfMemoryError.29.3F) - a 170MB tiff should not be a problem. If you need help with the actual image analysis side, you may reach a more focused audience by sending a mail to the [ImageJ list](http://imagej.net/Mailing_lists). The [docs](http://imagej.net//docs/) and [wiki](http://imagej.net/) also provide good learning resources.

Comment: Yes, I got that error and it said X amount (max) had been used. I actually just tried opening the .tiff image on a desktop with more memory (allocated 2000Mb for ImageJ) and it opened fine...It confused me before because there would be, for example, 1GB available in ImageJ, but it would run out of memory opening a 170Mb file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, set your scanner software to use grayscale mode. This will reduce the file size and give you better dynamic range compared to color mode. Saving as TIFF is the best bet.

If the scanner does not support saving in 16-bit grayscale, you can convert it once you open it in ImageJ (Image > Type > 16-bit).

Alternative background subtraction methods that work with 8-bit images are available in Process > Subtract Background or the Background Subtractor in the [Mosaic](http://mosaic.mpi-cbg.de/?q=downloads/imageJ) plugins.

Comment: As I said in the comment above, I got it to work on a more powerful desktop. Not sure what the issue was previously but it would not open no matter what I tried. This is useful information in terms of opening it as 16 bit in ImageJ so thank you! Now to process things...